# How can I include another article in MediaWiki?

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

I have an article already written about a subject, but I want to include a summary of it on another page with the "See also" link. So how do I include part of the other page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Extension:Labeled_Section_Transclusion, on mediawiki.org:

> This extension allows selective
>   transclusion of marked-off sections of
>   text.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the extension a previous poster mentioned, you can do a very simple version of this using completely vanilla mediawiki's {{:page}}, and ..
(and possibly  if you want a slightly differeht effect.

I placed an example in my mediawiki at http://wiki.andy.glew.ca/wiki/Example_of_a_summary_in_vanilla_mediawiki

Note that while I made the summary a complete section, you could make it a single line or just a few words.